# Does ASP.NET MVC 4 cache pages by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been reading about how you can configure caching durations and such with attributes, but by default, does it have any caching of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It would be impossible to determine if a page could be cached for any amount of time. Think of all the variables in play: is it user dependent? Time dependent? Random variable dependent? Automatic caching would be a nightmare.

Edit: Having said that, it's possible that a browser might cache a page that is a GET request that has the same query string that it has sent before. If you want to tell the browser that it should not cache results for an action, you could decorate it with the output cache attribute:

[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is only client-side caching (unless you specify [`OutputCacheAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which would get in to server-side caching)

Comment: Ah, so the client is able to detect that the page is the same? My understanding was the client sends a request saying I have version X of this page, and the server replies saying me too, nothing has changed, which prevents the download of the full page.